# How to apply text over image and have the image be responsive based on text?

Tags: html, css

I have a text field that is present over an image. Whenever a user adds to the text field in my Rails app it pushes down on the text box, which I want. However I want the text box to permanently stay on the image and have the image extend down. So really the image needs to be a flexible container for the text box.

Right now I have the following code.

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.something-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.something-text {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
} 

.bottom-box {
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
          <img class="img-responsive something-img" src="http://placehold.it/900x100" />
          <div class="col-sm-8 something-text text-center">
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p><p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
            <p>Here are some words but typically a lot more are present here.</p>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bottom-box">
      <h2>Words Go Here</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

It works in the sense that the text box is on top of the image but it fails to push the image down and additional sections also from going down. Is this something that can be addressed with just plain CSS?

EDIT:
I cannot do a background image to the section.

Comment: use background image ...

Comment: Due to some webpacker issues I can't.